# Shiny - conditional Output

Tags: r, shiny

I am already aware about "ConditionalPannel" that hides an output but still computes it.
I would like to know if there is a way to prevent shiny from computing the output at all (in certain particular cases)

Typically I would like to be able to write in my ShinyUI function (mainPannel block) something like:

```
if (bool) {showOutput('comp2', 'nvd3')}
```

where bool would be a global variable that would be dependent on reactive inputs. I am especially thinking to a checkboxInput defined within ShinyUI

```
checkboxInput("comparison", p("Compare trips?", value = FALSE)
```

Hence bool would be defined in server.R as:

```
bool <<- FALSE

output$comp1 <- renderChart({
 if (input$comparison) {
  rs <- compare_acc(select(), select2())
  } else {
  rs <- exception_handler
 }
 rs$set(dom = "comp1")
 bool <<- input$comparison
 return(rs)
 })
```

**However it is not working as bool keeps to be equal to FALSE.
I have also tried "reactiveValues" :**

In global.R:

```
values <- reactiveValues()
values$bool <- FALSE
```

In Server.R:

```
output$comp1 <- renderChart({
 if (input$comparison) {
 values$bool <<- TRUE
 rs <- compare_acc(select(), select2())
 } else {
  rs <- exception_handler
  values$bool <<- FALSE
  }
 rs$set(dom = "comp1")

return(rs)
})
```

In ui.R

```
if (values$bool) {showOutput('comp1', 'nvd3')},
```

but I still can't make it work as I get the following error:

```
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something      that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
```

Any help please?

Comment: Hi, you should take a look at `reactiveValues`

Comment: Hi Stéphane, Many thanks for your prompt answer! Actually I did try reactiveValues but I got no luck with that. Maybe you could point me in the right direction? I edited my post with my code using reactiveValues

Comment: Sorry I misread the question. The `if...` in `ui.R` cannot work. Why don't you simply return an empty chart in `output$comp1` ?

Comment: Actually it is what I am doing at the moment through "exception_handler". The issue is that it is still loading nvd3 library that is conflicting with leaflet that I also use in this shiny page (I guess there is a CSS conflict as I cannot see the circles I draw on the map as soon nvd3 is launched through output$comp1). Thus my goal was to prevent this conflict to happen in most cases...